# std::vector<std::vector<T>> как альтернатива двумерного массива

Tags: c++

Есть библиотека на Фортране, в ней функция:

```
SUBROUTINE func(oarr)
  REAL oarr(100,1000)
  ...
```

Необходимо вызвать эту функцию из программы на С++. Насколько корректным будет такой код:

```
extern "C" {
  void func(float** array);
}

std::vector<std::vector<float> > td_array(100, std::vector<float>(1000, 0.0));
func( &(*(td_array.begin()->begin())) );
```

Comment: А вы проверяли, это вообще будет работать? Каким образом функция знает размер передаваемого ей массива?

Comment: `float**` это не двумерный массив, это указатель на указатель.

Comment: @YuriyOrlov, добавил конкретики в вопрос

Comment: Сколько магических чисел) Такое тяжело назвать "библиотекой" -)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Он не будет корректным, вектор векторов Вам никак не подойдёт, т.к. он никак не может быть сконвертирован во `float**`. 
Если мы возьмем адрес так: `&td_array[0]`, то получим `std::vector<float>*` который мы никак не можем преобразовать во `float*`, а нам нужно именно это при обходе этого «массива». Поэтому, используйте «голый» двойной указатель, а не вектор векторов.

Вообще, взаимная конвертация массивов, векторов и указателей работает только в одной плоскости. n-мерные сущности между собой не конвертируются.

Answer (score 3):

Ваш код не скомпилируется, потому как вы передаёте в функцию `float*`, а не `float**`. При принудительном касте вызовется ошибка выполнения. Вы передаёте в функцию лишь указатель на элемент `td_array[0][0]`, При фиксированно заданной длине функция может пробежаться до последнего элемента первого вектора - `td_array[0][n - 1]`, и на этом всё, о существовании остальных векторов у функции сведений нет.